# How to use PendingResult to make Network call Synchronously

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

On Application launch i Hit a service to get some data/feeds, data if get from this request is dependent for most parts of application.

I have checked Google implementation of Tag Manager. They use `PendingResult` to block the thread, unless the time or the network request is completed.

I am also trying to use the same approach, but there are not much tutorials of how `PendingResult` actually works. I have done following.

```
  if(aManager.getContainer() == null){
        PendingResult pending= aManager.init();
        pending.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    **In AManager Class**




public PendingResult init(String containerID){

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    fetchType= db.getFetchMode();
    this.containerID= containerID;

    if(fetchType== 0){
        refresh();
    }

        return null;
    }
```

I am returning `null` because i am unable to understand how to return PendingResult object?

**on refresh();** I make network request by using volley

Comment: `PendingResult`?
 you dont mean `android.content.BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult` ? so what `PendingResult`do you mean?

Comment: @pskink I want ` pending.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to wait for 10 seconds or unless i get response from service, and once i get result i want application to perform other tasks. I don't know much about `PendingResult`, but i looked at TagManager example, and it uses PendingResult to do this.

Comment: what is the full class name of that `PendingResult`?

Comment: @pskink public class AManager{

  public PendingResult init(String containerID){}
}

Comment: if you have `String` class the full class name is `java.lang.String`, for `Activity` class it is `android.app.Activity`, so my question is: what is the full class name for that `PendingResult`?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver.PendingResult`  does not have `await` method

Comment: @pskink : apologies. I am using this one com.google.android.gms.common.api. PendingResult<R extends Result>

Comment: @Kirmani88 I suggest you to bloack the UI using a loading indicator until the service is executed and then using a callback you can update the application.

Comment: @fightingCoder block thread by using PendingResult or some other method?

Comment: yes you can block the UI thread using a loading indicator. No need to use pending intent.

Comment: so should i use Thread.sleep to block UI thread?

Comment: @Kirmani88 please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the service start an ProgressDialog with a loading indicator. The ProgressDialog will block the UI. After the service is executed completely you post an event to your activity using eventBus and from that event dismiss the loading indicator.

Please see the code below to show the progress Dialog:

```
public static MaterialDialog showProgressDialog(Context context) {
        if (null != context) {

            MaterialDialog.Builder builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                    .content("Loading...")
                    .theme(Theme.LIGHT)
                    .widgetColorRes(color.progress_dialog_theme)
                    .progress(true, 0);

            MaterialDialog dialog = builder.build();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
//            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                                     KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH
                            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU;
                }

            });
            return dialog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @Kirmani88 Please mark this as the answer if you were able to solve it. Thank you.